# No start database manager command was issued. SQLSTATE=57019

Tags: database, db2, database-administration

I am new to DB2 and I have installed DB2 9.7.

I created an instance which is shown below

```
[sathish@oc3855733574 ~]$ db2ilist
sathish
```

Settings of /etc/services is shown below

```
DB2_sathish     60000/tcp
DB2_sathish_1   60001/tcp
DB2_sathish_2   60002/tcp
DB2_sathish_END 60003/tcp
DB2_TMINST      50000/tcp
```

But, when I start using 'db2start' it throws the following error

```
07/31/2015 10:26:20     0   0   SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
```

I installed DB2 using 'root' and starting 'DB2' from 'instance' (sathish in this case)

Any help or URL link will be of great use

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a look into db2diag.log file and I got a unusual hack from one of the website

I followed the steps mentioned below and it worked

```
a)   db2trc on -f db2trace.out
b)   db2start
c)   db2trc off
```

Comment: I think it's the second command `db2start` that is the important one. It fixed it for me.

Comment: this is a misleading answer. playing with the logs has nothing to do with fixing corrupted instance. it may be because of inappropriate libs or corrupted instance. db2fm may help. the next link may help too: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21648521

Answer (score 3):

This problem generally occurs if you have recently changed the password of the account which is the owner of that db2 instance what you need to do is go to services-> properties of the db2 instance -> and then from log on part select local system account

Comment: This can be a comment and not answer. Please, read the rules.

Comment: I don't know why this should be a comment but this definitely was the answer for me. Whilst the error itself seems to be something else the solution was far more simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like something is wrong with the installation. There should be some hints on what DB2 ran into in the db2diag.log file (look under ~/sqllib/db2dump/db2diag.log).

What you could do if the db2diag.log does not provide a clue is to verify your installation is correct. DB2 includes a tool for that named "db2val". Here is the [link to the documentation of db2val for version 9.7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0053565.html). Just run "db2val" as the instance owner and check the output.

Comment: Output of 'db2val'

[sathish@oc3855733574 ~]$ db2val
DBI1335I  Installation file validation for the DB2 copy installed at
      /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7 was successful.
DBI1342E  Instance sathish does not exist in the current DB  copy.
Explanation: 
The specified instance does not exist in the current DB2 copy and will
not be validated.

User response: 
Rerun the db2val command with an instance that is listed by the db2ilist
command for the current DB2 copy.
DBI1344E  The validation tasks of the db2val command failed. For     details, see the log file /tmp/db2val-07_31_14:19:01.log.

Comment: Is the instance "sathish" shown when running db2ilist (I suppose so because of the first output in your question)? What is the account for the instance owner?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is meant by that.  I google'd but I could not find answer.  What command should be executed to know the account of an 'instance owner'

Comment: You performed the DB2 installation as root and then probably specified that "sathish" should be the administrator. From that account, could you: `db2ilist`? If it shows that "sathish" is available, then could you try `db2start` again? When it fails, look for error details in the db2diag.log file as described above. Paste the error.

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
db2start
```

then connect to database

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo -i -u db2inst1 /database/config/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2start
```

For more information

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49807/sql1641n-error-on-linux-while-running-db2start-using-db2-express-c-on-linux-luw