# Excel VBA Connect to IBM Db2

Tags: vba, excel, db2, database-connection, connection-string

Currently, I'm trying to query a Db2 instance from VBA but am having hard time finding proper documentation or previous stack questions that provide complete answers.

When I run the below, I receive an error:

"SQL1032N No start database manager command was issued.
SQLSTATE=57019"

Current connection code:

```
Sub connect()

    Dim conn As Object 'Variable for ADODB.Connection object
    Dim rs As Object 'Variable for ADODB.Recordset object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=IBMDADB2.1;Server=servername;Database=dbname;Port=port;Data Source=DB2;ProviderType=OLEDB;UID=uid;PWD=pw"
    conn.Open

    rs.Open "Select * .....", conn
    rs.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

Thanks yall

Comment: that error is unfamiliar to me so I guess it is less likely to be an ADO/VBA error and more likely to be a provider specific error.  Try changing tags and tag this Q with DB2?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31740042/1188513 - looks like a DB2 installation issue.

Comment: If the Db2-server is also running on the same workstation as the VBA, then you need to *start* the Db2 services. To do this, it is easy (as local admin) to run db2cwadmin.bat and in the resulting window run `db2start` command.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the idea SMeaden. I've checked out that link already Mathieu but thanks anyway. @mao they are not running on the same workstation but thanks for the try

Comment: Have you got the correct actual  dbname, port, uid, and pw in your string here `Database=dbname;Port=port;Data Source=DB2;ProviderType=OLEDB;UID=uid;PWD=pw`

Comment: @P.Vernon yes, I just didn't want to share it online. But yes, I used the same info that I used on DB2 configuration assistant to add database to DB2 client

Comment: can you connect to your database using the same details but with a different client   e.g some JDBC client.  Otherwise check db2 is running on the server (and run db2start on the server if not)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to connect with your same code but a different connection String - `Provider=IBMDADB2.1;Hostname={hostname};Port=3910;Database={dbname};ProviderType=OLEDB;UID={user};PWD={password}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference for anybody who stumbles upon this question in the future, I was able to successfully connect with the following:

```
Dim conn As Object 'Variable for ADODB.Connection object
Dim rs As Object 'Variable for ADODB.Recordset object

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=IBMDADB2.1;UID=" & username & ";PWD=" & password & ";Data Source=ABCDB1;ProviderType=OLEDB"
conn.Open
```

Note: username and password are strings assigned appropriate credentials

This works on my machine with Windows 7, client DB2 installed, and Excel 2010 over a private/secure LAN network

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that. The code seems to work. If you have an ODBC connection setup (which already handles all the connection intricacies) then the ConnectionString is very simple, simply put the ODBC connection name:

```
Dim conn As Object 'Variable for ADODB.Connection object
Dim rs As Object 'Variable for ADODB.Recordset object

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.ConnectionString = "<YourODBCConnectionName>"
conn.Open

rs.Open "Select * from <schema>.<tableName> fetch first 10 rows only", conn
rs.Close
conn.Close
```